# Stripe Checkout - Backend validation - Unused token

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a small form interface where users can add the amount of money they want to load into their account. Users have to load a minimum amount of money. So I need to reject if users put an amount less then certain amount (ie. 50 USD).

I have js validation on place for the form for minimum load. Users put the desired amount then click checkout. After the checkout process stripe js api returns with a token. Token with other data (like amount, currency) are sent to server.

Now I need to validate the amount in the server. I can check the amount and print error message if it does not validate. The token that stripe js api created will remain unused if the validation is rejected.

My question is, what are the problems that can arise if I keep the token unused?

Answer (score 0):

So actually, you don't need to validate on your server.  If you attempt to call the [Create a Charge API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with a value less than the minimum (in any currency) Stripe will simply raise an error (400 Bad Request).

**Example in Python:**

```
>>> stripe.Charge.create(amount=49, currency="usd", source="tok_visa")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 17, in create
response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)
  File "~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 153, in request
resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 365, in interpret_response
self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 178, in handle_error_response
raise err

stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_xxx: Amount must be at least 50 cents
```